# Calculate Maximun, Minimun, Average of n numbers

Tags: python, max, average, min

The question is to write    a   program that    asks    the user    to  enter   a   series  of  numbers and output, the maximum number in the series, the minimum number in the series, and the average of all the POSITIVE numbers.

The current code I have calculates for the minimum and maximum, but I don't know how to write a code to make it calculate the average.

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
num = None

while True:
     inp = input("PLease enter a number: ")
     if inp == "#" : 
     break
     try:
    num=float(inp)
    except:
    print ("Error with this input")
    continue

    if maximum is None:
    maximum = num
    minimum = num

    if num>maximum: 
    maximum=num
    if num<minimum: 
    minimum=num

print ("The Maximum is ", maximum)
print ("The Minimum is ", minimum)
```

Comment: Looks like your code is not formatted correctly. Also try using library functions, whenever possible. In your case, use `max()` , `min()` and `sum()`

Answer (score 2):

You store all inputted numbers in a list and calculate from there:

```
def avg_pos(d):
    if len(d) == 0: # avoid div by 0
        return 0
    return sum(d)/len(d)

data = []
while True:
    try: 
        n = input("Number: ")
        if n == "#": 
            break
        n = int(n)
        data.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")

print( f"Min: {min(data)}  Max: {max(data)}  AvgP: {avg_pos([d for d in data if d>0])}" )
```

Output:

```
Number: 4
Number: 5
Number: 6
Number: -2
Number: -99
Number: 73
Number: #
Min: -99  Max: 73  AvgP: 22.0
```

Comment: If the user enters an incorrect input the incorrect input is still appended. For example "test"  and this later throws an error when comparing it at `d >0`. Adding the `continue` after the print in the exception would prevent this.

Comment: @ggordon My bad, fixed. moved the append inside the try: - no need to continue

Answer (score 1):

Find the sum each time a positive number is accepted and count each number. At the end you can determine the average

```py
maximum = None
minimum = None
sum_of_positive = 0
count_of_positive = 0
num = None

while True:
    inp = input("PLease enter a number: ")
    if inp == "#" : 
        break
    try:
        num=float(inp)
    except:
        print ("Error with this input")
        continue

    if maximum is None:
        maximum = num
        minimum = num

    if num>maximum: 
        maximum=num
    if num<minimum: 
        minimum=num
    
    if num > 0:
        sum_of_positive = sum_of_positive + num
        count_of_positive = count_of_positive + 1

if count_of_positive > 0:
    average_of_positive = sum_of_positive / count_of_positive
else:
    average_of_positive = 0

print ("The Maximum is ", maximum)
print ("The Minimum is ", minimum)
print ("The Average of Positive Numbers is ", average_of_positive)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `counter` variable to know how many rounds you got in the loop.
And also you need a `total` variable to sum all the `num`

Then you just need to print total/counter

Comment: This could have been just a simple comment

Answer (score 0):

Use library functions like `max`, `min` and `sum`.

For example `max([1,2,3,5,11,8])` gives you 11, `min([1,2,3,5,11,8])` gives you 1 and `sum([1,2,3,5,11,8])` gives you 30.

So lets say you read the numbers in to a list named `numbers`, then getting the maximal number is `max(numbers)`, the minimal is `min(numbers)` and the average is `sum(numbers)/len(numbers)`.

Please notice that if you use python 2 then you need to convert to float before dividing, like this `float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)`.